# vuetify data table mobile view

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

i need a solution to style vuetify's data table in mobile vue to add some margin between rows
to look like the image below

[image]

and this is how it looks like per default on vuetify

[image]

this is codepen link for the vuetify example

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ThugMa/pen/BaWpBbj?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is the way to do it but twisting the css can do what you want.

https://codepen.io/michael-vascue/pen/KKWaKZo

```
.v-data-table>.v-data-table__wrapper .v-data-table__mobile-table-row {
  margin: 10px; // add margin between each row
  border: 1px solid #ededed; // add border color
  display: block; // display table row as block
}
```